# Telethon выдает ошибку

Tags: python, telethon

```
Cannot find any entity corresponding to "-1288484910"
```

Выдает ошибку telethon, когда пытаюсь получить участников группы.

Первый вариант:

```
client.get_participants('-12345')
```

Второй вариант:

```
client.get_participants(client.get_entity('-12345'))
```

Оба выдают одинаковую ошибку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества нужно решить ошибку